# calculate sum or product based on input

Tags: linux, bash

I am asking user to enter 2 numbers and s for sum, or "p" for product.
when I run the script I don't see any results
here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "please enter two integers, s or p to calculate sum or  product of this numbers: "  num1 num2 result
if [ result == "s" ]
then
echo "num1+num2" | bc

elif [ result == "p" ]
then
echo $((num1*num2))

fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement [chepner's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43175213/45375), which explains the problem with the code in the question well, with a solution inspired by [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)<sup>[1]</sup>
:

```
# Prompt the user.
prompt='please enter two integers, s or p to calculate sum or product of this numbers: '
read -p "$prompt" num1 num2 opChar

# Map the operator char. onto an operator symbol.
# In Bash v4+, consider using an associative array for this mapping.
case $opChar in
  'p')
    opSymbol='*'
    ;;
  's')
    opSymbol='+'
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Unknown operator char: $opChar" >&2; exit 1
    ;;
esac

# Perform the calculation.
# Note how the variable containing the *operator* symbol
# *must* be $-prefixed - unlike the *operand* variables.
echo $(( num1 $opSymbol num2 ))
```

---

<sup>[1] Except for `read`'s `-p` option, the solution is POSIX-compliant; it does, however, also work in `dash`, which is mostly a POSIX-features-only shell.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing the string `result`, not the value of the variable `result`.

```
if [ "$result" = s ]; then
    echo "$(($num1 + $num2))"
elif [ "$result" = p ]; then
    echo "$(($num1 * $num2))"
fi
```

Inside `$((...))`, you can omit the leading `$` because a string is assumed to be a variable name to be dereferenced.

There's no reason to use `bc` if you intend to restrict the inputs to integers.